# the ShareActionProvider doesn't work

Tags: android

i create a menu with a menuitem that works with ShareActionProvider

it works well.
but if the menuitem does not shown as an action,when the menuitem is clicked,it does nothing.

and so i wrote like this

```
onOptionItemSelected(...){
    if(item.getitemid()==r.id.mi_share){
          item.getactionprovider.onperformaction();
    }
}
```

i thought it would work. but it does nothing.
i found the method onPerformAction in ShareActionProvider does nothing ,just return false;

so what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

i found the mistake.

the actionProvider must be written in menu.xml but written in code.